# Highcharts: Second series won't plot on second axis

Tags: plot, highcharts

Okay Everyone, I'm a highcharts beginner but I've tried pouring over the tutorials and I'm still not seeing my mistake.  I'm trying to replicate a graph made in Excel with a spline plot over a percentage stacked bar graph.  However hard I try I cannot seem to get the spline series to plot on the secondary axis with the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Acumun Data Visualization</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-    beta1/jquery.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: "Degree Type by Cohort"
    },
    xAxis: [{
      categories: ['2006', '2007','2008', '2009','2010','2011','2012',
                '2013','2014'],
  crosshair: true
}],

yAxis: [{//primary Y Axis
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  min: 0,
  max:100,
  labels: {
    format: '{value}%',
    style: {
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
          },
    title: {
      text: '% Degree Composition',
      style: {
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
      }
    }, {//Secondary axis
      min: 0,
      max: 350,
      gridLineWidth:1,
      title:{
        text: 'Cohort size',
        style: {
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
      },
      labels: {
        format: '{value}',
        style: {
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
              },
      opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
      shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: 'percent'
      }
    },
    series: [{ //Bachelors data
      name: 'BS',
      type: 'column',
      //yaxis: 1,
      data: [1,27,75,121,145,136,45,64,59]
    }, { //Masters data
      name: 'MS',
      type: 'column',
      //yaxis: 1,
      data: [8,21,46,54,68,77,44,32,44]
    }, {//PhD Data
      name: 'PhD',
      type: 'column',
      //yaxis: 1,
      data: [22,57,54,78,84,74,45,46,48]
    }, { //Cohort Size - Spline plot
      name: 'Cohort Size',
      type: 'spline',
      yaxis: 1,
      data: [31,105,175,253,297,287,134,142,151]
    }]
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a simple typo. In the spline series, change yaxis to yAxis.

Code was...

```
...
}, { //Cohort Size - Spline plot
  name: 'Cohort Size',
  type: 'spline',
  yaxis: 1,
  data: [31,105,175,253,297,287,134,142,151]
}]
...
```

Code should be...

```
...
}, { //Cohort Size - Spline plot
  name: 'Cohort Size',
  type: 'spline',
  yAxis: 1,
  data: [31,105,175,253,297,287,134,142,151]
}]
...
```

Comment: Sweet merciful crap!  Of course it's going to be that simple.  Oh well, that's for the heads up.  I knew I must be looking right through it.  I was so paranoid about proper comma placement I totally overlooked proper camelCase syntax.